# Brute Force for solving Diophantine equation

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, code-review

I'm trying to solve the following  Diophantine equation using Mathematica:
$$2^x=5^y+3$$

I have a code,but is very slow. Can we speed up ?

```
f[x_?IntegerQ, y_?IntegerQ] := 2^x - 5^y;
M = 2000;
sol = Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ (Most /@ 
Select[Flatten[Table[{x, y, f[x, y] == 3}, {x, 0, M}, {y, 0, M}], 
1], #[[3]] &]) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {50.2135, {{x -> 2, y -> 0}, {x -> 3, y -> 1}, {x -> 7, y -> 3}}}*)
```

Another code with `For` function:

```
For[i = 0, i <= M, i++, 
For[j = 0, j <= M, j++, 
If[f[i, j] == 3, Print[{i, j}]]]] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{49.4506, Null}*)
```

Calculating time is about 50 second.
[image]

In Maple with `M=2000`,Maple can solve this with about `2.094` second.

Comment: `Flatten[ParallelTable[If[2^x == 3 + 5^y, {x, y}, Nothing], {x, 0, 2000}, {y, 0, 2000}], 1]` does about 10 seconds on my machine. I'm not sure if Maple will use multiple cores by default when you loop that way.

Comment: Well, the simplest trick is that $y$ should not be exceed $x/2+1$.

Comment: You are comparing an exact computation with a floating point computation. That should give one possible speed-up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In version 10.1 on my circa 2011 PC:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 M = 2000;
 r = Range[0, M];
 xx = 2`^r;
 yy = -(5`^r);
 grid = # + yy & /@ xx;
 Position[Round@grid, 3] - 1
]
```

> ```
> {3.3214, {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {7, 3}}}
> ```

By luck it seems in this instance `Round` isn't actually needed:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 M = 2000;
 r = Range[0, M];
 xx = 2`^r;
 yy = -(5`^r);
 grid = # + yy & /@ xx;
 Position[grid, 3`] - 1
]
```

> ```
> {1.70207, {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {7, 3}}}
> ```

---

If *actual* "brute force" is not the goal, then perhaps:

```
RepeatedTiming[
  M = 2000;
  r = Range[0, M];
  sol = 2`^r ⋂ 5`^r + 3
]

x -> Log[2, sol]
y -> Log[5, sol - 3]
```

> ```
> {0.00485, {4., 8., 128.}}
>
> x -> {2., 3., 7.}
>
> y -> {0., 1., 3.}
> ```

Comment: neat answer! Happy New Year.

Comment: (1+) Your approach is the best(for speed).Thanks

Comment: @Mariusz You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Can you please explain how is this approach is 'the best' for speed? It scales quadratically whereas linear is possible. Would be curious to see the performance for M=100000.

Comment: @yarchik. With yours code for M=500000 I have only one solution: `{1,3}`.And where are the next two?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk `M=500000` is a "grid" with 250,000,000,000 elements; that cannot work.  I thought you wanted a brute-force solution, and that's what I wrote.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Well, it is two solutions, not one. Only the values of $y$ are printed. The trivial $y=0$ solution is obtained by starting the loop from 0, i.e. `{y,0,500000}`. I was under impression that the limit of large $x$ and $y$ is of interest. However, if goal was to find just some trivial solutions $x,y<10$ why bother at all with "brute force approach". `Solve[2^x - 5^y == 3 && 0 <= x < 10 && 0 <= y < 10, {x, y}, Integers]` works just fine. This can be coupled with a tiny bit of analytical work showing that no other exists.

Comment: @yarchik "Brute force" usually means a computational attack with no analytical work.  Usually this *only* works in smaller cases, and one must be more intelligent (e.g. your approach) as the problem scale increases.

Comment: What is `sol` ?

Comment: @Mariusz Sorry, bad code copy.  I am interested in your intent with this question; were you just using this as a toy example for a couple of loops, or were you actually looking for a better approach to finding solutions?  I interpreted it as the former.

Comment: It does not seem important since there are no solutions with `y > 22`, but the floating-point representation is not faithful for `y > 22`, because ``5`^y`` has a round-off error of at least `1`, which error increases with `y`. There is no such problem for ``2`^x`` because FP is binary. Suppose `X = 2^x` *were* equal to `5^23 + 3` exactly and ``Y = 5`23``. Then ``X = 5^23 + 3;
Y = 5`^23;
X - Y`` yields `4.`, not `3.`. -- One possible fix is ``With[{prec = 1 + r*Log10[5.]},
 sol = SetPrecision[2`^r, Infinity] ⋂ SetPrecision[(N[5, #] & /@ prec)^r + 3, Infinity]
 ]``.

Comment: @yarchik One might add to Mr.Wizard's definition that in *brute force* the computational attack usually makes an exhaustive check of all cases in a given search space, which in the OP is given as `M * M` pairs of integers with `M = 2000`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for bringing your superior numerical understanding to this; I should try to be more careful.  Old habits from Project Euler showing through; false answers were not punished, so I'd try to the naive approach before looking for sources of error.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe double loop is not necessary:

```
Reap[Do[If[IntegerQ[Log[2, 5^y + 3]], Sow[y]], {y, 100000}]]
```

Takes around 12 seconds.

Comment: Ok, but this is nowhere near the scale of the original question ($2000\times2000$). How long would your solution take compared to that?

Comment: @MarcoB Right, my solution is 50 times faster! 100000 vs 2000.

Comment: Can squeeze out a bit more with finite precision using `With[{l5y = Log[2, N[5, 50]^y + 3]}, 
 If[Round[l5y] == l5y, Sow[{Round[l5y], y}]]]` inside that loop.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That is an order of magnitude improvement!

Answer (score 6):

This is an incomplete answer to a question that was not asked. One can show that there are no solutions in intervals in a way that is much faster than exhaustive search. I'll give the general idea but I'm not going to make a rigorous proof.

First we rewrite by taking the base-2 logarithms of both sides.

x = log_2(5^y+3) =
  log_2(5^y (1+3/5^y)) =
  y log_2(5) + 3/log(2) 5^(-y) + O(5^(-2*y)) (which assumes y>=1)

Since `x` is an integer we require that`y` times the base-2 log of 5 be "close" to an integer, for integer-valued `y`. The place to look for candidates is the denominators of the convergents of continued fraction approximations to log_2(5).

```
In[1]:= cc = Convergents[ContinuedFraction[N@Log[2, 5]]]

(* Out[1]= {2, 7/3, 65/28, 137/59, 339/146, 1493/643, 9297/4004, \
20087/8651, 29384/12655, 49471/21306, 177797/76573, 227268/97879, \
4268621/1838395, 4495889/1936274, 31243955/13456039, \
35739844/15392313} *)
```

We already know that `y=1` and `y=3` give valid solutions. Let's suppose we checked by brute force that there are no solutions for `y` between 4 and 28. The next "good" candidate value is `y=59`. Well, in principle maybe some other value between 29 and 58 would work? Here is what we know from the convergents list. The fraction 137/59 is closer to log_2(5) than any other rational with denominator no larger than 59. So let's check how close it is.

```
In[2]:= N[137/59 - Log[2, 5], 20]

(* Out[2]= 0.00010580341772239789239 *)
```

So it is around 10^(-4) away. If `y` is in the range `{29,59}` then the first correction term is far smaller than this, since it is bounded below by 3/log(2)*5^(-29):

```
In[3]:= N[3/Log[2] 5^(-29), 20]

(* Out[3]= 2.3236230070198052257*10^-20 *)
```

What this shows is that no value for `y` in the range `{29,30,...,59}` will give an integer value for log_2(5^y+3). One can handle successive ranges by moving from one denominator to the next. For example, the maximum value our first-order correction gives in the ninth such interval is far to small to make up the difference between the closest rational approximation and log_2(5) with suitably bounded denominator in that interval.

```
{d9, d10} = Denominator /@ cc[[9 ;; 10]]
minDistToInteger9 = N[cc[[10]] - Log[2, 5], 20]
maxAvaliableInInterval9 = N[3/Log[2] 5^(-d9), 20]

(* Out[7]= {12655, 21306}

Out[8]= 4.8483327777503868560*10^-10

Out[9]= 1.4821457784228658814*10^-8845 *)
```

My guess is that there are no more solutions besides the ones already found. But I have no idea how one might prove that.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk The proof is simple: $5^y = -3 (\text{mod} 1024) \Rightarrow c = 163 (\text{mod} 256)$. Thus, we have a contradiction mod 257.

Comment: @yarchik I'm not Mariusz, but...that mod 1024 vs 257 approach 's pretty neat.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I was inspired by your analysis. And I included Mariusz because I thought he may be interested to know that there are no other solutions even though the question was formulated as optimization of a brute force approach.

Answer (score 4):

Slight variation of @Mr.Wizard solution.

```
m = 2000;
range1 = Range[0, m];
range2 = Range[0, Ceiling[Log[5, 2^m - 3]]];
AbsoluteTiming[Position[Outer[Plus, 2^range1, -5^range2], 3] - 1]
```

> {0.924582, {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {7, 3}}}

**Original answer:**

This approach reduces time to ~20sec

```
m = 2000;
pts = Tuples[Range[0, m], 2];

slope1 = (Ceiling[Log[5, 2^m - 3] + 5] - 100)/m;
slope2 = (Floor[Log[5, 2^m - 3] - 5] + 100)/m;
sel = (#2 <= slope1 #1 + 100 && slope2 #1 - 100 <= #2) & @@@ pts;
pt4 = Pick[pts, sel];
Pick[pt4, UnitBox[2^#1 - 5^#2 - 3 & @@@ pt4], 1]
```

> {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {7, 3}}

We are basically crating an envelope around log function.

```
log = Table[{m, Log[5, 2^m - 3]}, {m, 2, 2000, 10}];
   pt2 = {{0, 0}, {0, 100}, {m, Ceiling[Log[5, 2^m - 3] + 5]}, {m, 
    Floor[Log[5, 2^m - 3] - 5]}, {0, -100}};
Graphics[{FaceForm[], Blue, Point@pt2, Magenta, Point@pt4, Green, 
  Point@log, EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[pt2]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: (1+)......Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 2^x == 5^y + 3;

m = 2000;

AbsoluteTiming[{#[[1]], #[[-1, -1]]} & /@
  (x /. 
    Solve[{eqn, 0 <= x <= m, 0 <= y <= m}, x, Integers])]

(* {2.3865, {{2, 0}, {3, 1}, {7, 3}}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cf = Compile[{{m, _Integer}},
   Do[
    If[Abs[2^x - 5^y - 3] < 10.^-12, Print[{x, y}]],
    {x, 0, m}, {y, 0, m}
    ], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

cf[2000] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2,0}
>   {3,1}
>   {7,3}
>   {0.171435,Null}

Note that overflow will occur.

```
Do[
  With[{y = Log[5, -3 + 2^x]}, If[Abs[FractionalPart@y] < 10.^-12, Print[{x, y}]]],
  {x, 0, 10^5}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.73022, Null}